# Margin left is moving my whole div to the left instead of just the text inside it

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to position my "My Header" by adding `margin-left` to it, but it keeps moving the whole div object instead of just the text.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/8denfw3h/

I am just trying to use the `margin-left` to add space to "My Header", which should shift it towards to the right, but it is not working.

The `margin-left` is adding the margin to the entire div object, not the "My Header" like I want it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you probably want padding not margin. Padding is inside, margin is outside the box

Comment: Think of it as, `margin` being added to the outside of the element while `padding` to the inside of the element.

Comment: If I add padding, it moves the entire div to the right. I don't want that.

Comment: are you talking about the div or the h1? In your question you talk about a div, but in your sample the margin is on the h1. So which is it?

Comment: Close the opening div tag. You have `<div class="myDiv"` in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `h1#aboutTitle` in order to get that margin-left. However, if you're just trying to align the text to the center I would remove the margin-left and use `text-align: center;` on the `h1#aboutTitle` CSS.

Also, you forgot your `>` on your `myDiv` in your fiddle.

```css
.myDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #EB3A6A;
}

h1#aboutTitle{
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;

}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
 <h1 id="aboutTitle">My Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I am so sorry. Thanks for your help. I did not realise I forgot the ```>``` in my div. I do apologise, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `text-align:left` to only move the text to the left direction

Comment: Okay, I get that, but I want to add a margin - how do I do that without it moving the entire div?

Comment: add a fixed value of margin-left